# Website with full-page sections in Drupal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I am building a website in Drupal. However, the default look seems pretty old-fashioned so I would like to have a more modern look. I have installed the Bootstrap theme, but I'm still not quite sure of how I can get a modern look like that of this website:

http://vertx.io/

In particular, I want the sections of my front page to stretch out to fill the entire width of the web page. Like for vertx's Scale, Polyglot, General purpose/unopinionated sections.

If it helps, this is the source code of the website, though I don't think it's written in drupal https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web-site

How should I implement such a feature? Would it be something like the panel module?

Answer (score 0):

The 'look' you are talking about is actually 'theme' in Drupal terminology. You do get few default themes with drupal installation but you are totally free to find / build and install other theme. Just google about it, i.e. "free drupal themes" or similar. You'll find sites like this:

https://www.devsaran.com/free-drupal-theme

https://www.weebpal.com/free-drupal-themes

https://www.freshdesignweb.com/responsive-drupal-themes/

and so on...

Comment: What is the name of the elements that house the different sections? Is it a block?

Comment: Sections are containers for the blocks. But sections them self are printed from page template (most likely: /sites/all/themes/your_theme/templates/page.tpl.php). And before they become available they must be declared in theme info file.